# More than one relationship to a class in a Class Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

In a class diagram, is it possible to have two classes with more than one relationship? For example, a generalization relationship and a composition relationship?

For instance,
[image]

You can have either a composition relationship or a generalization relationship. A frozen Chocolate `is a` chocolate. But if you destroy the chocolate class the frozen chocolate class would also be destroyed. which also makes it a composition relationship.

But can you have both on the same diagram, or would you have to stick to one? Which one in this case?

Comment: I don't see a composition relationship. Can you declare a `FrozenChocolate frochoc;` in the Chocolate class?

Comment: You mean create an object FrozenChocolate?

Comment: If you had to have a frozen Chocolate class. Why wouldn't it not be a composition relationship with the chocolate class?

Comment: That's what composition means. Every instance of `Chocolate` will have its own `FrozenChocolate` object, which doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: If thats what it means then why dont you see a composition relationship?

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalization relationship, `FrozenChocolate` is a `Chocolate` but adds extra properties. It is not a compositions, you cannot say that `Chocolate` has a `FrozenChocolate`.

Your argument about destroying `Chocolate` resulting in `FrozenChocolate` also being destroyed is invalid. These are not object instances. You cannot say that destroying `Animal` means that `Dog` is destroyed.